# iOS7 crash with In-app purchase

Tags: ios, crash, in-app-purchase

with Xcode 5, iOS 7

I have a class(LHBBuyService) to deal with In-app purchase. It has a corresponding store front view to buy products.

Mostly it works well if user open the store front view then wait for response.

But
When a user open the store front view, then navigate away quickly before App Store send a response back, and open some other views.

It crashes on both simulator and device.

I got this crash log:

> [LHBBuyService respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated
>   instance 0x2e7b4eb0

I think maybe the reason is when the store front view is loaded, I add a observer in its viewDidLoad() function:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
```

But when it is navigated away, its delegate is also used to receive messages from App Store, so I remove the observer in viewWillDisappear:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
```

But I still got crash, Anyone can help me out?
Thanks a lot!

LHBBuyService source code:

```
#import "LHBBuyService.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"

#define Rgb2UIColor(r, g, b)  [UIColor colorWithRed:((r) / 255.0) green:((g) / 255.0) blue:((b) / 255.0) alpha:1.0]

@implementation LHBBuyService{
    PoetryDao *poetryDao;
}

-(void) viewDidLoad{
    self.view.backgroundColor = Rgb2UIColor(102, 153, 204);
    self.msgLabel.backgroundColor = Rgb2UIColor(102, 153, 204);

    poetryDao = [[PoetryDao alloc] init];

    _buyBtn.enabled = NO;
    _restoreBtn.enabled = NO;

    _productID = @"com.lihappy.poetry.iphone";

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
    {
        self.request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                        initWithProductIdentifiers:
                        [NSSet setWithObject:self.productID]];
        self.request.delegate = self;

        [self.request start];

        //发起请求1，请求待购买的产品信息，开始等待
        [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

    }
    else
        _msgLabel.text = @"Please enable In App Purchase in Settings";

}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
}


- (IBAction)buyItem:(id)sender {
    @try{
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:_product];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

        //发起购买请求2
        [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    }@catch(NSException *e){
        NSLog(@"%@", e);
    }
}

- (IBAction)restoreBtnPressed:(id)sender {
    @try {
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];

        //发起恢复请求
        [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"%@", exception);
    }
    @finally {

    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKProductsRequestDelegate

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{

    //收到请求1返回的产品信息
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

    NSArray *products = response.products;

    if (products.count != 0)
    {
        _product = products[0];
        _buyBtn.enabled = YES;
        _restoreBtn.enabled = YES;
    } else {
        _msgLabel.text = (@"无法连接苹果服务器，请重试");
    }
}

-(void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
    _msgLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"请求失败，请连接网络，或注销已登陆的app store帐号后重试！%@", error];
}


-(void) paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error{
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
    _msgLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"没有已购买的产品，请点击“购买”按钮！！%@", error];

}

-(void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue{
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"transactions finished.");

}

-(void) requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request{
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"request did finish.");

}

-(void) paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{
    //收到购买请求2的返回
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self unlockFeature];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
                 finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                _msgLabel.text = @"请求失败，请连接网络，或注销已登陆的app store帐号后重试";
                NSLog(@"请求失败，请连接网络，或注销已登陆的app store帐号后重试");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
                 finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                _msgLabel.text = @"已经买过，诗词已解锁";
                NSLog(@"already have");
                [self unlockFeature];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                _msgLabel.text = @"处理中...";
                NSLog(@"purchasing...");
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

}

-(void)unlockFeature
{
    _msgLabel.text = @"购买成功!所有诗词已解锁!";

    //update database
    BOOL isUpdateOk = [poetryDao updateAllLicense:1];

    if(isUpdateOk){

        NSArray *viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
        UIViewController *rootViewController = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:viewControllers.count - 2];

        ListTableViewController *vc = (ListTableViewController *)rootViewController;

        vc.poetryArray = [[[PoetryDao alloc] init] getAllListWithBasicInfo];
        [vc.tableView reloadData];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"购买成功" message:@"所有诗词已解锁" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

        [self performSelector:@selector(dismissAlert:) withObject:alert afterDelay:1];


    }else{
        _msgLabel.text = @"解锁诗库失败，请重试";
    }
}

-(void)dismissAlert:(UIAlertView*)alert{
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
}
@end
```

Some related crash logs:

```
    CoreFoundation`___forwarding___:
0x1fa3510:  pushl  %ebp
0x1fa3511:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x1fa3513:  pushl  %ebx
0x1fa3514:  pushl  %edi
0x1fa3515:  pushl  %esi
0x1fa3516:  subl   $60, %esp
0x1fa3519:  calll  0x1fa351e                 ; ___forwarding___ + 14
0x1fa351e:  popl   %eax
0x1fa351f:  movl   %eax, -16(%ebp)
0x1fa3522:  cmpl   $0, 12(%ebp)
0x1fa3526:  setne  %al
0x1fa3529:  movzbl %al, %esi
0x1fa352c:  movl   8(%ebp), %ecx
0x1fa352f:  movl   4(%ecx,%esi,4), %eax
0x1fa3533:  movl   %eax, -20(%ebp)
0x1fa3536:  movl   (%ecx,%esi,4), %ebx
0x1fa3539:  movl   %ebx, (%esp)
0x1fa353c:  calll  0x209b4da                 ; symbol stub for: object_getClass
0x1fa3541:  movl   %eax, %edi
0x1fa3543:  movl   %edi, -28(%ebp)
0x1fa3546:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
0x1fa3549:  calll  0x209b408                 ; symbol stub for: class_getName
0x1fa354e:  movl   %eax, -24(%ebp)
0x1fa3551:  movl   -16(%ebp), %eax
0x1fa3554:  movl   1394666(%eax), %eax
0x1fa355a:  movl   %eax, -32(%ebp)
0x1fa355d:  movl   %eax, 4(%esp)
0x1fa3561:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
0x1fa3564:  calll  0x209b41a                 ; symbol stub for: class_respondsToSelector
0x1fa3569:  testb  %al, %al
0x1fa356b:  je     0x1fa358f                 ; ___forwarding___ + 127
0x1fa356d:  movl   -20(%ebp), %eax
0x1fa3570:  movl   %eax, 8(%esp)
0x1fa3574:  movl   -32(%ebp), %eax
0x1fa3577:  movl   %eax, 4(%esp)
0x1fa357b:  movl   %ebx, (%esp)
0x1fa357e:  calll  0x209b48c                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x1fa3583:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x1fa3585:  je     0x1fa358f                 ; ___forwarding___ + 127
0x1fa3587:  cmpl   %ebx, %eax
0x1fa3589:  jne    0x1fa3788                 ; ___forwarding___ + 632
0x1fa358f:  movl   -16(%ebp), %esi
0x1fa3592:  leal   1071604(%esi), %eax
0x1fa3598:  movl   %eax, 4(%esp)
0x1fa359c:  movl   -24(%ebp), %edi
0x1fa359f:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
0x1fa35a2:  movl   $10, 8(%esp)
0x1fa35aa:  calll  0x209bbfa                 ; symbol stub for: strncmp
0x1fa35af:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x1fa35b1:  je     0x1fa379d                 ; ___forwarding___ + 653
0x1fa35b7:  movl   1394638(%esi), %esi
0x1fa35bd:  movl   %esi, 4(%esp)
0x1fa35c1:  movl   -28(%ebp), %edi
0x1fa35c4:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
0x1fa35c7:  calll  0x209b41a                 ; symbol stub for: class_respondsToSelector
0x1fa35cc:  testb  %al, %al
0x1fa35ce:  je     0x1fa3816                 ; ___forwarding___ + 774
0x1fa35d4:  movl   -20(%ebp), %eax
0x1fa35d7:  movl   %eax, 8(%esp)
0x1fa35db:  movl   %esi, 4(%esp)
0x1fa35df:  movl   %ebx, %edi
0x1fa35e1:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
0x1fa35e4:  calll  0x209b48c                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x1fa35e9:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x1fa35eb:  je     0x1fa3870                 ; ___forwarding___ + 864
0x1fa35f1:  movl   %edi, -32(%ebp)
0x1fa35f4:  movl   -16(%ebp), %ebx
0x1fa35f7:  movl   1394614(%ebx), %ecx
0x1fa35fd:  movl   %ecx, 4(%esp)
0x1fa3601:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x1fa3604:  movl   %eax, -24(%ebp)
0x1fa3607:  calll  0x209b48c                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x1fa360c:  movl   %eax, -28(%ebp)
0x1fa360f:  movl   (%eax), %eax
0x1fa3611:  movzwl 26(%eax), %eax
0x1fa3615:  shrl   $6, %eax
0x1fa3618:  andl   $1, %eax
0x1fa361b:  movl   12(%ebp), %ecx
0x1fa361e:  cmpl   %ecx, %eax
0x1fa3620:  movl   -20(%ebp), %eax
0x1fa3623:  je     0x1fa367b                 ; ___forwarding___ + 363
0x1fa3625:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x1fa3628:  leal   1042458(%ebx), %eax
0x1fa362e:  movl   %eax, -20(%ebp)
0x1fa3631:  leal   1096367(%ebx), %esi
0x1fa3637:  testl  %ecx, %ecx
0x1fa3639:  movl   %esi, %edi
0x1fa363b:  cmovnel %eax, %edi
0x1fa363e:  calll  0x209b4fe                 ; symbol stub for: sel_getName
0x1fa3643:  movl   -28(%ebp), %ecx
0x1fa3646:  movl   (%ecx), %ecx
0x1fa3648:  movzwl 26(%ecx), %ecx
0x1fa364c:  movl   %edi, 16(%esp)
0x1fa3650:  movl   %eax, 8(%esp)
0x1fa3654:  leal   1414454(%ebx), %eax
0x1fa365a:  movl   %eax, 4(%esp)
0x1fa365e:  andl   $64, %ecx
0x1fa3661:  shrl   $6, %ecx
0x1fa3664:  testw  %cx, %cx
0x1fa3667:  cmovnel -20(%ebp), %esi
0x1fa366b:  movl   %esi, 12(%esp)
0x1fa366f:  movl   $4, (%esp)
0x1fa3676:  calll  0x1fda310                 ; CFLog
0x1fa367b:  movl   1395506(%ebx), %eax
0x1fa3681:  movl   1394646(%ebx), %ecx
0x1fa3687:  movl   8(%ebp), %edx
0x1fa368a:  movl   %edx, 12(%esp)
0x1fa368e:  movl   -24(%ebp), %edx
0x1fa3691:  movl   %edx, 8(%esp)
0x1fa3695:  movl   %ecx, 4(%esp)
0x1fa3699:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x1fa369c:  calll  0x209b48c                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x1fa36a1:  movl   %eax, -20(%ebp)
0x1fa36a4:  movl   %ebx, %esi
0x1fa36a6:  movl   -32(%ebp), %ebx
0x1fa36a9:  movl   %ebx, (%esp)
0x1fa36ac:  calll  0x209b4da                 ; symbol stub for: object_getClass
0x1fa36b1:  movl   1394670(%esi), %edi
0x1fa36b7:  movl   %edi, 4(%esp)
0x1fa36bb:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x1fa36be:  calll  0x209b41a                 ; symbol stub for: class_respondsToSelector
0x1fa36c3:  testb  %al, %al
0x1fa36c5:  je     0x1fa36dc                 ; ___forwarding___ + 460
0x1fa36c7:  movl   -20(%ebp), %eax
0x1fa36ca:  movl   %eax, 8(%esp)
0x1fa36ce:  movl   %edi, 4(%esp)
0x1fa36d2:  movl   %ebx, (%esp)
0x1fa36d5:  calll  0x209b48c                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x1fa36da:  jmp    0x1fa3702                 ; ___forwarding___ + 498
0x1fa36dc:  movl   %ebx, (%esp)
0x1fa36df:  calll  0x209b4e0                 ; symbol stub for: object_getClassName
0x1fa36e4:  movl   %eax, 12(%esp)
0x1fa36e8:  movl   %ebx, 8(%esp)
0x1fa36ec:  leal   1414470(%esi), %eax
0x1fa36f2:  movl   %eax, 4(%esp)
0x1fa36f6:  movl   $4, (%esp)
0x1fa36fd:  calll  0x1fda310                 ; CFLog
0x1fa3702:  movl   1428286(%esi), %eax
0x1fa3708:  movl   -20(%ebp), %ecx
0x1fa370b:  cmpb   $0, (%ecx,%eax)
0x1fa370f:  movl   -28(%ebp), %eax
0x1fa3712:  movl   %ecx, %ebx
0x1fa3714:  je     0x1fa374c                 ; ___forwarding___ + 572
0x1fa3716:  movl   (%eax), %eax
0x1fa3718:  testb  $-128, 26(%eax)
0x1fa371c:  je     0x1fa374c                 ; ___forwarding___ + 572
0x1fa371e:  movl   1428278(%esi), %ecx
0x1fa3724:  movl   (%ebx,%ecx), %ecx
0x1fa3727:  movzbl 24(%eax), %edx
0x1fa372b:  addl   20(%eax), %edx
0x1fa372e:  movl   (%ecx,%edx), %ecx
0x1fa3731:  movl   8(%ebp), %edi
0x1fa3734:  movl   (%edi,%edx), %edx
0x1fa3737:  movl   (%eax), %eax
0x1fa3739:  movl   8(%eax), %eax
0x1fa373c:  movl   %eax, 8(%esp)
0x1fa3740:  movl   %ecx, 4(%esp)
0x1fa3744:  movl   %edx, (%esp)
0x1fa3747:  calll  0x209ba0e                 ; symbol stub for: memmove
0x1fa374c:  movl   1428274(%esi), %eax
0x1fa3752:  movl   (%ebx,%eax), %edi
0x1fa3755:  movl   1394674(%esi), %eax
0x1fa375b:  movl   %eax, 4(%esp)
0x1fa375f:  movl   -24(%ebp), %eax
0x1fa3762:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x1fa3765:  calll  0x209b48c                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x1fa376a:  movsbl (%eax), %eax
0x1fa376d:  cmpl   $68, %eax
0x1fa3770:  je     0x1fa377b                 ; ___forwarding___ + 619
0x1fa3772:  cmpl   $100, %eax
0x1fa3775:  jne    0x1fa377f                 ; ___forwarding___ + 623
0x1fa3777:  fldl   (%edi)
0x1fa3779:  jmp    0x1fa3793                 ; ___forwarding___ + 643
0x1fa377b:  fldt   (%edi)
0x1fa377d:  jmp    0x1fa3793                 ; ___forwarding___ + 643
0x1fa377f:  cmpl   $102, %eax
0x1fa3782:  jne    0x1fa3793                 ; ___forwarding___ + 643
0x1fa3784:  flds   (%edi)
0x1fa3786:  jmp    0x1fa3793                 ; ___forwarding___ + 643
0x1fa3788:  shll   $2, %esi
0x1fa378b:  movl   8(%ebp), %ecx
0x1fa378e:  movl   %eax, (%ecx,%esi)
0x1fa3791:  xorl   %edi, %edi
0x1fa3793:  movl   %edi, %eax
0x1fa3795:  addl   $60, %esp
0x1fa3798:  popl   %esi
0x1fa3799:  popl   %edi
0x1fa379a:  popl   %ebx
0x1fa379b:  popl   %ebp
0x1fa379c:  ret    
0x1fa379d:  movl   1330030(%esi), %eax
0x1fa37a3:  cmpb   $0, (%eax)
0x1fa37a6:  je     0x1fa37e0                 ; ___forwarding___ + 720
0x1fa37a8:  movl   %ebx, 4(%esp)
0x1fa37ac:  movl   $0, 24(%esp)
0x1fa37b4:  movl   $0, 20(%esp)
0x1fa37bc:  movl   $0, 16(%esp)
0x1fa37c4:  movl   $0, 12(%esp)
0x1fa37cc:  movl   $0, 8(%esp)
0x1fa37d4:  movl   $21, (%esp)
0x1fa37db:  calll  0x1f54050                 ; __CFRecordAllocationEvent
0x1fa37e0:  movl   -20(%ebp), %eax
0x1fa37e3:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x1fa37e6:  calll  0x209b4fe                 ; symbol stub for: sel_getName
0x1fa37eb:  movl   %ebx, 16(%esp)
0x1fa37ef:  movl   %eax, 12(%esp)
0x1fa37f3:  addl   $10, %edi
0x1fa37f6:  movl   %edi, 8(%esp)
0x1fa37fa:  leal   1414374(%esi), %eax
0x1fa3800:  movl   %eax, 4(%esp)
0x1fa3804:  movl   $3, (%esp)
0x1fa380b:  calll  0x1fda310                 ; CFLog
0x1fa3810:  int3   
0x1fa3811:  jmp    0x1fa390c                 ; ___forwarding___ + 1020
0x1fa3816:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
0x1fa3819:  calll  0x209b40e                 ; symbol stub for: class_getSuperclass
0x1fa381e:  movl   %eax, %edi
0x1fa3820:  movl   %ebx, (%esp)
0x1fa3823:  calll  0x209b4e0                 ; symbol stub for: object_getClassName
0x1fa3828:  movl   %eax, %esi
0x1fa382a:  testl  %edi, %edi
0x1fa382c:  jne    0x1fa384d                 ; ___forwarding___ + 829
0x1fa382e:  movl   %ebx, (%esp)
0x1fa3831:  calll  0x209b4e0                 ; symbol stub for: object_getClassName
0x1fa3836:  movl   %eax, 16(%esp)
0x1fa383a:  movl   %esi, 12(%esp)
0x1fa383e:  movl   %ebx, 8(%esp)
0x1fa3842:  movl   -16(%ebp), %eax
0x1fa3845:  leal   1414390(%eax), %eax
0x1fa384b:  jmp    0x1fa385e                 ; ___forwarding___ + 846
0x1fa384d:  movl   %esi, 12(%esp)
0x1fa3851:  movl   %ebx, 8(%esp)
0x1fa3855:  movl   -16(%ebp), %eax
0x1fa3858:  leal   1414406(%eax), %eax
0x1fa385e:  movl   %eax, 4(%esp)
0x1fa3862:  movl   $4, (%esp)
0x1fa3869:  calll  0x1fda310                 ; CFLog
0x1fa386e:  movl   %ebx, %edi
0x1fa3870:  movl   -20(%ebp), %ebx
0x1fa3873:  movl   %ebx, (%esp)
0x1fa3876:  calll  0x209b4fe                 ; symbol stub for: sel_getName
0x1fa387b:  movl   %eax, %esi
0x1fa387d:  movl   %esi, (%esp)
0x1fa3880:  calll  0x209b504                 ; symbol stub for: sel_getUid
0x1fa3885:  cmpl   %ebx, %eax
0x1fa3887:  je     0x1fa38ae                 ; ___forwarding___ + 926
0x1fa3889:  movl   %eax, 16(%esp)
0x1fa388d:  movl   %esi, 12(%esp)
0x1fa3891:  movl   %ebx, 8(%esp)
0x1fa3895:  movl   -16(%ebp), %eax
0x1fa3898:  leal   1414422(%eax), %eax
0x1fa389e:  movl   %eax, 4(%esp)
0x1fa38a2:  movl   $4, (%esp)
0x1fa38a9:  calll  0x1fda310                 ; CFLog
0x1fa38ae:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
0x1fa38b1:  calll  0x209b4da                 ; symbol stub for: object_getClass
0x1fa38b6:  movl   -16(%ebp), %ecx
0x1fa38b9:  movl   1394166(%ecx), %esi
0x1fa38bf:  movl   %esi, 4(%esp)
0x1fa38c3:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x1fa38c6:  calll  0x209b41a                 ; symbol stub for: class_respondsToSelector
0x1fa38cb:  testb  %al, %al
0x1fa38cd:  jne    0x1fa38fb                 ; ___forwarding___ + 1003
0x1fa38cf:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
0x1fa38d2:  calll  0x209b4e0                 ; symbol stub for: object_getClassName
0x1fa38d7:  movl   %eax, 12(%esp)
0x1fa38db:  movl   %edi, 8(%esp)
0x1fa38df:  movl   -16(%ebp), %eax
0x1fa38e2:  leal   1414438(%eax), %eax
0x1fa38e8:  movl   %eax, 4(%esp)
0x1fa38ec:  movl   $4, (%esp)
0x1fa38f3:  calll  0x1fda310                 ; CFLog
0x1fa38f8:  int3   
0x1fa38f9:  jmp    0x1fa390c                 ; ___forwarding___ + 1020
0x1fa38fb:  movl   %ebx, 8(%esp)
0x1fa38ff:  movl   %esi, 4(%esp)
0x1fa3903:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
0x1fa3906:  calll  0x209b48c                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x1fa390b:  int3   
0x1fa390c:  calll  0x209b8e2                 ; symbol stub for: getpid
0x1fa3911:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x1fa3914:  movl   $9, 4(%esp)
0x1fa391c:  calll  0x209b930                 ; symbol stub for: kill
0x1fa3921:  nopw   %cs:(%eax,%eax)
```

Comment: are you using simulator

Comment: @iTroyd23  Yes, I use simulator to get this crash log. But this app crashes in both simulator and device.

Comment: Please post the (symbolicated) stack trace.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks, but I don't know what is (symbolicated)stack trace, I posted some crash logs, is it right?

Comment: No, I'd like to see the stack trace, which is generated within Xcode when the process crashes (ensure you have a breakpoint to catch Objective-C exceptions).

Comment: No, that's not the stack trace.

Comment: @trojanfoe So Sorry. I'll google and learn how to get symbolicated stack trace, then will let you know.